# How do I use React hooks and set states with useInterval

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I understand useInterval allows you to pass functional components as parameters, so I'm trying to take advantage of that and setting states with values used inside a functional component.
In the following code, I want the ExecutionsPage to fetch projectScans and isProjectScansFetchComplete, which are returned from the useFetchProjectScansByUser() hook as an array:

```
1 const ExecutionsPage: React.FC = () => {
2     let user:string|null = sessionStorage.getItem('user')
3     const UPDATE_TABLE_TIMER: number = 30000; // Time (ms) until we call the API again to update the scans table
4     const [stateProjectScans, setStateProjectScans] = useState<Array<IProjectScan>>([]);
5     const [stateIsProjectScansFetchComplete, setStateIsProjectScansFetchComplete] = useState<boolean>(false);
6     function CallProjectScans(){
7         let [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete] = useFetchProjectScansByUser(user)
8         return [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete]
9     }
10    useEffect(() => {
11       let [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete] = CallProjectScans()
12       // @ts-ignore
13        setStateProjectScans(projectScans)
14       // @ts-ignore
15        setStateIsProjectScansFetchComplete(isProjectScansFetchComplete)
16    }, [])
17    const GetProjectScans = () => {
18        let [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete] = useFetchProjectScansByUser(user);
19        setStateProjectScans(projectScans)
20    };
21    // @ts-ignore
22    useInterval(GetProjectScans(), UPDATE_TABLE_TIMER)
```

In using this code, I'm getting this error: "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."
So, with all that said, here are my questions:

1. Readability-wise, am I using too many functions?
2. The goal is to call the React hook on line 7 every 30 seconds and update the states on lines 4 and 5. Is there a better way to do this than how I'm currently attempting it?
3. I tried using useEffect() to prevent the aforementioned error (by setting the states on the initial render of the ExecutionsPage, instead of rerendering it), but I am still getting it. Why?

Edit: Here's the function definition of useFetchProjectScansByUser():

```
export const useFetchProjectScansByUser = (user: string|null): [IProjectScan[], boolean] => {
    const [projectScans, setProjectScans] = useState<IProjectScan[]>([]);
    //update here
    const [isProjectScansFetchComplete, setIsProjectScansFetchComplete] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const {enqueueSnackbar, } = useSnackbar();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        /*function callJSONFunction(json) {
                let projectScans: IProjectScan[] = createProjectScansFromJSON(json);
                setProjectScans(projectScans);
        }*/
            const fetchProjectScans = async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch(URL);
                    if (!response.ok) throw response.statusText;
            
                    const json = await response.json();
                    let projectScans: IProjectScan[] = createProjectScansFromJSON(json);
                    setProjectScans(projectScans);
                ...
                finally {
                    setIsProjectScansFetchComplete(true);
                }
            };
            fetchProjectScans();
        }
    }, []);
    return [projectScans, isProjectScansFetchComplete];
}
```

Comment: You really need to remove these @ts-ignore errors, they are critical errors and you are adding more of them on top of your last question without fixing them. It is very difficult to assess your question because there is so much.  You are getting an infinite loop, likely because again, your `useInterval` function while I do not know how it's implemented, almost guaranteed expects a function callback as its argument. Instead you are calling a function, which itself sets state during render, and re-renders the component infinitely. Pass a function, solve the error you are hiding with ts-ignore

Comment: I would think the answer lies in your useFetchXYZ hook. You should modify it to return a function that causes it to refresh the data. Perhaps an `update` function. You are running into all kinds of trouble using hooks in ways that aren't intended. You are mixing coding patterns from traditional JS (declaring local vars, overriding them) vs React, which expects very specific usage of hooks & state setting to detect and react to state changes/re-render pages.

Comment: Do you want to paste your `useFetch` hook ?

Comment: You are *really* breaking the rules of hooks. The `useFetchProjectScansByUser` hook can't be called in nested functions and callbacks, like `CallProjectScans` and `GetProjectScans` functions.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I've just edited the post with the useFetch hook. Thanks for all your help

Comment: In the commented part of the function, I was thinking to use useInterval and do setProjectScans(projectScans) every 30 seconds. But how would this work when you're returning the values of the hook to another component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, your hook uses state to store the results of the last call to the server.

If you want to modify/update that state, you should make your sever call in the `useEffect` fire again by adding a new state variable and passing it to the dependency array. You can then pass back to the hook caller a way to update that dependency array, so in effect you can control the update from outside the hook.

This is exactly how hooks should work: compartmentalize logic, and expose a simple API to the consumers of the hook.

```
export const useFetchProjectScansByUser = (user: string|null): [IProjectScan[], boolean] => {
    // make new state variable to control useEffect firing
    const [update, setUpdate] = useState(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("I will fire every time the update var changes")
        console.log("Instead of only on mount")
    }, [update]) // pass the state var to dep array
    // create a function that will update state reliably every call
    const updateFunc = () => setUpdate((v) => v+1)
    // pass it back to the hook consumer
    return [X, Y, updateFunc]
}

const MyComponent = () => {
     // now we have an update function to call from the consumer
     const [X, Y, update] = useFetchProjectScansByUser('user')

     useEffect(() => {
         // call the update function every 3 seconds, which will re-run the hook useEffect
         const id = setInterval(() => update(), 3000)
         return () => clearInterval(id)
     }, [])
     // if a hook state updates, this component which consumes that hook will re-render
     // thus X and Y will be updated.
     return <div>{X} {Y}</div>
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I implement this logic: ```Type error: Type '{ projectScans: IProjectScan[]; isProjectScansFetchComplete: boolean; updateFunc: () => void; }' is not assignable to type '[IProjectScan[], boolean]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'projectScans' does not exist in type '[IProjectScan[], boolean]'.``` I tried specifying a void function return type, and it still didn't work.

Comment: @web-dev-nerd199 actually you really need to click into this exception. What is throwing the error? Look into that. Something is expecting the type `'[IProjectScan[], boolean]'`, and you're trying to assigning the new outputs to it. Again tho the void function type doesn't have to do with this error. This error says you are trying to assign our new return type ([A, B, C]) to something thats expecting [A, B]. Do you see yourself doing that somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

One of the first rules of hooks is: [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

So, you'd need to change your code and move every React hook to the top. As stated in the docs you cannot even return earlier before another hook. Anyway, to fix the code then you need to remove the React hook `useFetchProjectScansByUser` from inside the functions.